# Supporting multiples sreens on the ipad when setting image programmatically

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to support all available screens in my universal monotouch application.

In one of my screens I have a full screen `UIImage` for showing a full screen image. The image name is bg.png. My screen just support portrait and I add some version of the image by below naming and size:

bg.png----->320x480

bg@2x.png------>640x960

bg-568h@2x.png----->640x1136

bg-Portrait.png----->768 × 1004

bg-Portrait@2x.png----->1536 × 2008

Also I use below code for assigning it to the background of the view:

```
sImage .Image = UIImage .FromFile ("ProjectRes/Images/bg.png");
```

While I added the image to all version but I do not know why the image have not suitable quality in the ipda retina or ipad and even on the iphone 5. Am I wrong in my code?

**EDIT**

I changed my codes to:

```
splashImage .Frame = new RectangleF (0,0,this.View .Bounds .Width ,this.View .Bounds .Height );
splashImage .Image = UIImage .FromBundle  ("ProjectRes/Images/bg");
```

but it is not working yet. If they are helpful, I added these codes in a method that I call it on the `ViewWillAppear` method of the screen.Is `ViewWillAppear` a good place for it?

Did I use a correct naming for ipad and iphone 5? I copied the suffix from splash image suffix in the resources. Is they are same for other images too?

Answer (score 0):

`FromFile()` [maps to](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.FromFile) UIImage’s `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` method, which doesn’t support UIKit’s image-naming suffix patterns. You should be able to use [`FromBundle()`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.FromBundle) instead, leaving off the “.png” suffix, to get the correct resource selected automatically.